# How to assign a shortcut key to the mouse?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

I have got a mouse with two additional buttons on the sides. How can I assign shortcut keys to the mouse buttons? For example, using side left button as ctr+w in order to close down a tab in chrome.

Operating system - Windows 8.
Mouse Model - HP 5 button optical comfort mouse.

Comment: Use the control panel that came with it

Comment: You need a properly driver (software) for your mouse to do it.

Comment: The ease of this task will depend highly on the brand of mouse you have and the customization ability of their software. Here is a list of 3rd party software which might or might not work: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-apps-for-customizing-a-mouse/

Comment: I downloaded the software for the mouse, but it still doesn't have any options for setting shortcut keys. It just lets you to interchange the functions of the buttons. @duDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually these 2 buttons are for browser back/forward, which you might want to keep.

If you really want to re-assign them and can't do this through mouse driver, try autohotkey, they're xbutton1 and xbutton2 in autohotkey. Below is an example script to remap the button to ctrl+w.

```
XButton1::Send {ctrl down}w{ctrl up}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Microsoft IntelliMouse auto-installed the Microsoft Mouse utility which has a Keystroke option to assign whatever key combo I want to whatever button I want.

I assumed this stuff was built-in to Windows, but from the comments it looks like it depends on the mouse/driver :-(

Answer (score 0):

@Bopy what mouse do you have?  I think that will help clear things up in the first instance :)

If it is a gaming mouse, or something slightly more advanced that the stock mice you can get from the likes of HP/Dell etc... it should have some drivers that you can install and then configure the buttons that way.

If it is a stock mouse, there may be some options within the Control Panel, however, that would rely on the drivers for the mouse supporting hotkey configuration.  Generally the buttons on the side of stock / simple mice are just useful for navigating forward and backwards within your Internet Browser.